# Mapfish 3 variables in scalebar processor

Tags: mapfish, mapfish-print

I would like to be able to change the units of the scalebar processor based on values sent in spec.json - It seems this should be possible from reading the docs, but I can't get it to work.

A snippet of my config.yaml below showing the relevant parts. The config does work until I attempt to use the ${mapUnits} variable instead of a distinct value.

**config.yaml**

```
      title: !string
        default: "" 
      mapUnits: !string
        default: "m" 
      scalebar: !scalebar
        width: 180
        height: 31
        createSubReport: false
        default:
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)"
          unit: ${mapUnits}
          geodetic: true
          fontSize: 8
          barSize: 8
          padding: 5
          intervals: 2
          align: center
          type: line
```

I am also declaring 'mapUnits' in the spec:

**spec.json snippet**

```
{
    "layout": "A4 Landscape",
    "outputFormat": "pdf",
    "attributes": {
        "mapUnits": "ft",
        "title": "My Map",
        "map": {
            "bbox": [-1910349.8815163244, 6214452.698830085, 1205906.228840141, 8182614.4527394315],
            "dpi": 150,
            "layers": [/*layer config*/]
        }
    }
}
```

Running this just produces the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid unit: ${mapUnits}`

Is what I am attempting to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enumerate all possible attributes in your `config.yaml`, eventually defining default values.

In your `*.json` you can assign values to those attributes.

MapFish Print will render your `*.jrxml` report using the values defined in your `*.json` (or the default values from `config.yaml`).

MapFish Print will not substitute values in your `config.yaml`. The syntax you are using is not supported. `unit` can only be `m`, `ft` or `deegress` (as stated in the [documentation](http://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/attributes.html#!scalebar)).

Comment: Thanks jrgocha - so to be clear, is it not possible to dynamically change the scalebar units? The only way would be to define new templates with a different scalebar configuration?

Comment: Yes @tom_h. You can do it using different templates in your `config.yaml`. Use the unit to append to the template name, like `A4_landscape_ft: !template` and `A4_landscape_m: !template`. My template names are always a concatenation of different options.

Comment: Ok thanks - it's a shame it can't be done dynamically, I am already using concatenations of options for other things (show/hide legend etc) so was hoping to avoid adding more! Thanks for your help